# Full react-admin powered front-end

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I was building a dashboard view in my `react-admin` app, using a custom route and a `List`. (I found the necessary doc in the [Custom App](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomApp.html) doc)

But ra's `List` component is bound to current route, location etc.

As I will show multiple lists I guess I may use `ListController` instead, with a custom view.

This approach lead me to an idea... Why not use react-admin to build both my app's admin and front-end ? I would be able to use the same dataProvider, authProvider, custom actions etc.

Do you, react-admin lovers, think it'd be good idea to try using ra components (List, Edit, ListController...) and leverage the power of ra to build a fully ui-customized production app ?

Is there a proof-of-concept out there ?

I wonder if I should give this a try (I really wan't to) and I'd love it if I could get feedback from developers who endeavored to do just that already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a good idea, and it should be relatively straightforward. React-admin controllers (ListController, EditController, CreateController) don't depend on the route explicitely. It's only because they are used as children of Route props that they receive route parameters (`rescource`, `id`) in their props. ListController and CreateController do need a `location` prop to work, because that's where part of their state comes from (the filters in the list, the default values in the create form). But if you pass your own `location`, it may work.

We could imagine refactoring these controllers to be completely route (and location) independent, but I'm afraid of the added complexity for handling filters in the URL.